# how to disable the line under text in text input android react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to render a text input in react-native(android) with and a line below it which am getting from `borderBottomWidth` property put when am typing there are two lines appearing which is not looking good and couldn't remove it i tried giving `underlineColorAndroid='transparent'` but didn't work

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet,TextInput } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          autoCapitalize='none'
          autoCorrect={false}
          underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
          style={styles.textInput}
         />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#000',
    padding: 8,
  },
  textInput: {
    paddingVertical: 0,
    marginHorizontal: 10,
    textAlign: 'center',
    height: 18,
    fontSize: 14,
    alignSelf: 'flex-start',
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderWidth:0,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    color: '#1ac9e8',
    minWidth: 48,
    borderColor: '#1ac9e8',
    fontFamily: 'Monaco'
  }
});
```

https://snack.expo.io/rylmazFSH

any workarounds ?[image: picture]

Answer (score 10):

Add autoCorrect={false} should remove underline but in some android devices it will not work as described in this [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18457)

**Try this it is working**

```
autoCorrect={false}
keyboardType="visible-password"
```

Snack link : https://snack.expo.io/@mehran.khan/underline-android

Comment: in the link you gave also when am commenting the keyboardtype it is still the same but with the `keyboardType="visible-password"` it is seems to be working strange!!

Answer (score 0):

```
underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
```

Comment: It works for me when I add it but when I go to another screen and come back, I start seeing the underline again

Answer (score 0):

Update the style of your textInput. I found the style from snack

```
  textInput: {
    paddingVertical: 0,
    marginHorizontal: 10,
    textAlign: 'center',
    height: 18,
    fontSize: 14,
    alignSelf: 'flex-start',
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderWidth:0,
    color: '#1ac9e8',
    minWidth: 48,
    fontFamily: 'Monaco'
  }



  <TextInput
    underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
        autoCorrect={false}
        keyboardType="visible-password"
style = {styles.textInput}
    />
```

Comment: Actually I need that bottom border line but if see there are 2 lines coming that second line while typing i need to remove

Comment: hey it doesn't seem to work can you add a working link ?